# How to create an HTML5 video element in iOS that will stay hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, video

I am trying to create a video element in HTML5/js so I will be able to download it fully to memory and play it without having to buffer.

The issue is when I create a video element in iOS, it will always display it's player in full screen when I start playing it.
It is possible to play a hidden video in iOS, if you use the video tag with the style "display:hidden".
However, when trying to do this with js code, it doesn't work.

```
function CreateVideoElement(url, callback)
{
    var element = document.createElement('video');
    element.hidden = true;
    element.controls = false;
    element.style.display = "none";
    element.autoplay = false;
    element.playsinline = true;
    element.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        callback();
    };
    element.src = url;
    return element;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `opacity: 0`?

Comment: Display: hidden; isnt a css property. Visibility: hidden; is though. You can also try display: none;

Comment: Ale Plo, I don't understand which of the code fields you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My coworker found the solution.
What I did is `video.playsinline = true;` but there is another legacy option that needs to be set.
`webkit-playsinline`, but it cannot be set this way because of the `-`.
So eventually he found out you need to set it with `setAttribute` so the solution that works is like so:

```
        function CreateVideoElement(url, callback)
        {
            var element = document.createElement('video');
            element.controls = false;
            element.style.display = "none";
            element.autoplay = false;
            element.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', 'webkit-playsinline');
            element.setAttribute('playsinline', 'playsinline');
            element.onloadedmetadata = function() {
                callback();
            };
            element.src = url;
            return element;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. full download of the video:

Built into the HTML5 video tag is the preload attribute.  preload="auto" tells the browser to download the whole video. (YMMV - Chrome downloads  "a lot" of the video, but not the entire thing).

Adding `element.preload = "auto"`  is the trick you are looking for.

2. is display:none not hiding the video?

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: No, preload "auto", is auto. It means it downloads just enough to play it, but it doesn't download everything to memory. So eventhough it tries to download enough, it has no way to predict everything, so it doesn't always work. Especially on high bit rate files.

Comment: When I create the video with document.createElement it doesn't seem to behave the same as when I just put it in a <video> tag in the HTML

Comment: ```<script> 
var video = document.createElement('video');
   video.style.display = "none";
  video.controls = false;
      video.muted = true;
      video.autoplay = true;
      video.playsinline = true;
      video.src = "https://cdn.api.video/vod/vi5CO6tSMhpatqo7FBZYnlLo/mp4/1080/source.mp4";
   var div = document.getElementById("div");
   div.appendChild(video); 
    console.log(video);

</script>```
Works in Safari & Chrome.  If you set autoplay & muted, the video downloads.

Comment: I tried to add "<div id="div"></div>" into html to do what you showed. It won't help either. Are you sure you are testing this on a phone and not a Mac?